# How can updating one field cause another to be updated without triggers?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a parameterised insert query in a C# program that fails with "String or binary data would be truncated". The query runs on a database with collation Latin1_General_BIN. If I run the query manually in SSMS then it is successful.

I am specifying the field sizes and the field types when setting the parameters.

All fields in the query are of type char, datetime and float. I set the parameter field types to exactly the same as the field types in the table.

The field that causes the problem is called email and is char(200) not null. If I try to set this field to anything longer than 1 character, then I get the error. If I leave it out of the update statement then the statement executes successfully. If I run the query in SSMS, including the email field, then it is successful.

If I set email to anything 1 character long or to empty string then the next field in the table is set! I don't even mention this other field anywhere in my program.

There are no triggers on the table.

SQL Server Standard Edition 64-bit version 10.50.4000.0 running on NT 6.1.

Here is the table definition: http://pastebin.com/rJfGcmsA

Here is my query:

```
update slcustm set 
 name=@name,address5=@address5,fax=@fax,email=@email,vat_reg_number=@vat_reg_number
,credit_category=@credit_category,price_list=@price_list,currency=@currency
,lang=@lang,invoices_printed=@invoices_printed,customer_class=@customer_class
,date_last_issue=@date_last_issue,edi_customer=@edi_customer
,invoice_customer=@invoice_customer,territory=@territory,letter_code=@letter_code
,analysis_codes4=@analysis_codes4,responsibility=@responsibility
,statement_customer=@statement_customer,credit_limit=@credit_limit
,address1=@address1 where customer=@customer
```

Here is the trace for an execution of the query: http://pastebin.com/6gX1NFit

Comment: what is your column type in SQL?

Comment: Show your code and your table definition, please. In particular, are the field types correct for `VARCHAR` vs. `NVARCHAR`, and is your value actually, you know, not too long? Collation almost certainly has nothing to do with it; rather, SQL Server is more than happy to truncate strings in some circumstances but not others.

Comment: Also note that the collation of the columns may be different to that of the database

Comment: You've set some of them wrong. Show the table structure and the code, and we'll show you where.

Comment: Have a look at your datetime values. If any are earlier than Jan 1, 1753 (minimum SQL Server datetime value), you will also get this error.

Comment: More information now included in the question. I have isolated the field.

Comment: @AdrianNasui The type of the problematic column is char(200). The error happens no matter what value I set it to, even empty string.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight I now don't think collation is the issue. The type of the problematic column is char(200). The error happens no matter what value I set it to, even empty string.

Comment: see @JeroenMostert's comment!

Comment: Also - any triggers on the table?

Comment: select the table in sql management studio, right click it go to script table as, create to, clipboard. paste here so we can see your table design

Comment: @Prospector Here is the table definition: http://pastebin.com/rJfGcmsA

Comment: @MartinSmith No triggers, as the question say. Here's the table definition: http://pastebin.com/rJfGcmsA

Comment: @JeroenMostert Here is the table definition: http://pastebin.com/rJfGcmsA

Comment: No need to spam the pastebin link all over the place, just include it in your question. And we still don't have your C# code -- how are you invoking the `UPDATE` query from your client?

Comment: Your table definition has problems, incidentally -- why `CHAR` everywhere rather than `(N)VARCHAR`, and why all empty columns as defaults rather than permitting `NULL` -- but that's probably not pertinent to the problem, so let's ignore it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Making sure the people that asked for it would see it. I agree with your criticism of the schema but it's from a major accounting system and we can't change it

Comment: Trace of query is here: http://pastebin.com/6gX1NFit

Comment: Show your C# code. If using ADO.NET show us where you set up the email parameter. If using an ORM such as Entity Framework show the query and the class representing the table. Based on the trace it seems that the issue is that the email parameter is defined as char(1). We can't say why that is without seeing how the query was generated.

Comment: `@address1='Xxxxxxxxxx  `  you're missing a ' to close the address

Comment: No repro [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/020ef/1) sure you're connected to the right database and or updating the same table? Your code doesn't use two part names so maybe you have a table in a different schema with the same name and different structure.

Comment: @MartinSmith I can't reproduce it with SQL in SSMS. I can only reproduce it with my program. The other fields in the right table are updated properly. Please see the results of the trace here: http://pastebin.com/6gX1NFit